# How to add a global symbol that can be bound by Python compiler?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, global, python-2.x, symbols

This is my first question so please be nice :) I am rather new to Python but I am very experienced in other programming languages (e.g. C++).

---

### UPDATE 2 - Solution Found

Thanks everyone for helping :) As the solution is "hidden" in comments I will repost it here.

Instead of

```
file_symbols = {}
```

the variable local_symbol must initially be added to the file_symbols dictionary:

```
file_symbols = { "local_symbol" : local_symbol }
```

For anyone reading this: all variable / class names posted here are not to be understood as actual useful names as these examples are synthetic in nature ;)

---

Well... now I have to figure out the FULL meaning of:

```
exec compiled_code in file_symbols
```

So far I thought it would do nothing more than updating the dictionary `file_symbols` with the symbols found in `compiled_code`.
But it actually does a bit more as it seems! :)

---

### UPDATE 1

Ok, my sample project below seems to be too simple to show the actual problem. Anyway, thanks for your already provided support! :)

In fact I want to first compile multiple *.py files which need access to a local symbol (class instance). All symbols coming from these compiled files shall be collected and then be used as an environment for OTHER code objects.

So I really need to do this
(note the following code shows the concept, not actual executable code):

```
class Functions:
    (...)

global_symbols = {}
local_symbol = Functions()

# note that the external files need to access local_symbol to call its functions!
for file in external_files:
    code = file.load()
    compiled_code = compile(code, "<string>", "exec")
    file_symbols = {}
    exec compiled_code in file_symbols
    global_symbols.update(file_symbols)

some_code = another_file.load()
compiled_code = compile(some_code, "<string>", "exec")
exec(compiled_code, global_symbols)
```

In this example the line

```
exec compiled_code in file_symbols
```

produces a NameError() - because there is no way they could access local_symbol as it is not **defined** anywhere in the external files although it shall be used!

So the question is how to provide access to local_symbol for the external_files so that they can call the instance's functions??

My import hook solution that some of you regard as "hack" was the only working solution so far. I would love to use a simpler one if there is any!

Thanks again :)

---

### My initial question was this:

So here we go. What I intend to do is advanced stuff and I did not find a solution to my problem neither here nor anywhere else.

Assume the following code in Python (2.6.x / 2.7.x):

```
class Functions:
    def __init__(self):
        (...)
    def func_1(...):
        (...)
    def func_2(...):
        (...)
    (...)
    def func_n(...):
        (...)
functions = Functions()
code = loadSomeFile(...)
compiled_code = compile(code, "<string>", "exec")
(...)
global_env = {}
local_env = {"func":functions}
exec(compiled_code, global_env, local_env)
```

where `code` in the example above is loaded from a file with a content that might look like this:

```
import something
(...)
def aFunction(...):
    a = func.func_1(...)
    b = func.func_2(...)
    return a * b
(...)
aFunction()
```

Please note that `(...)` in the code above means that there might be more code that I left out for the sake of simplicity.

The problem I encounter in my example is that the compiler raises an error for this line:

```
compiled_code = compile(code, "<string>", "exec")
```

I will get this error: `NameError("global name 'func' is not defined")`

This error is totally understandable as the compiler can't bind to any global symbol with the name "func". But I still want to compile the code this way.

So the obvious question is:

How can I define global symbols that can be used by the compiler for `compile()` statements so that the compiler will bind any "unknown" symbol to an object of my choice?

In my example I would like to define a global symbol `func` that is bound to an instance of `class Functions` so that the compiler will find this symbol when compiling code which makes use of `func` as seen in the example above.

So how can this be accomplished?

**Important:**
Please note that I am aware that directly executing the code using `exec(...)` would fix the compilation problem because the dict `local_env` in the example above would provide the symbol that is required for successful execution. HOWEVER I can't do it this way because the code that shall be compiled is not small at all. It might consist of hundreds of code lines and this code is also not executed only once but many many times.
So for performance reasons I really need to compile the code rather than directly executing it.

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Can't you use `exec` instead of `compile`? Something like `exec(..) in compiled_code`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that without compilation it would work but I can't do it this way because the code that is compiled for code is MUCH more complex than in the example. It might even consist of hundreds of lines of code. Therefore I really want to compile it because this way it executes MUCH faster!
Also note that the code is executed multiple times across the actual project and not just once.

Comment: The normal way to handle this would be for the code being compiled to explicitly import any external entities that it needs.  If the compile call is failing, then it sounds like the code is missing an import.

Comment: No there is no import missing because the code that shall be compiled can't import the 'func' symbol from anywhere as it is not available in form of an import file! The 'func' symbol must be bound to a variable that is defined in the module that compiles the code.

Comment: Python isn't going to raise any NameErrors when you *compile* code. Those would only happen when you *execute* the code. It sounds to me like you've misunderstood something about `exec`.

Comment: However the compiler needs to bind available names to something when they are used. Otherwise the code cannot be converted to executable byte code. Well, anyway... The error is resolved with my own answer now :)

Comment: @OliK: [You can compile code that uses nonexistent variables with no problem.](http://ideone.com/LE3vim)

Comment: Ok you may be right that compiling the code may work even without any binding to actual functions. 
Well actually right after compilation I do something like this in my real project to create my own code dictionary for a code environment that is used when executing OTHER code objects:
`exec compiled_code in definitions` The resulting definitions object is then used to update my local_env environment which is actually used for other compiled code objects during their execution as an local environment. So you see - it's a lot more difficult than you think.

Comment: What's wrong with `file_symbols = {"local_symbol": Functions()}`?

Comment: Nothing actually :) This is the solution to my problem :) However I need to understand what exactly `exec compiled_code in file_symbols` really means. I found no good documentation for this rather exotic looking use of exec. So far I thought that this statement does nothing more than to update the provided dictionary `file_symbols` with all symbols found in `compiled_code`. But that seems not to be the full story...?!

Comment: `exec` executes the given code with the given dictionary as the code's symbol table. If all you're doing is assignment statements then it just looks like it's updating the dictionary. But there may be more complicated side effects which are seen elsewhere (like a print statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't provide separate `globals` and `locals` dicts to `exec`. That causes the executed code to behave as if it's embedded in a class definition. That means that **any variable lookups in functions defined in the `exec`uted code bypass `locals`.**

```
>>> exec("""
... def f():
...     print a
... f()""", {}, {"a": 3})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in f
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
>>> exec("""
... def f():
...     print a
... f()""", {"a": 3})
3
```

Just pass a `globals` dict.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please review my updated question as this is the real problem that I face.

Comment: @OliK: I'm still not seeing why you can't just put `func` in the globals dict.

Comment: Sure I can and in fact I have it done this way in my project's code. But the error happens earlier (see update).

Comment: @OliK: Why aren't you putting `func` in `file_symbols`? (And are you sure you want to `exec` these code snippets in separate dicts, but merge their entries into a single dict? That seems like a great way to confuse yourself about what code sees what variables.)

Comment: Well to be hostest while unserstanding most of Pythons concepts the line `exec compiled_code in file_symbols` is not totally clear to me. All I found out was that it returns the symbols of the code objects to which it is applied. Now looking at your comment it seems that it would help to initially add local_symbol to it. So my questions is: What actually DOES this statement if not ONLY returning the symbols found in a code object? I have found no documentation for this rather strange use of the exec statement nor was I able to logically find out what it actually and fully does! :)

Comment: And yes, I know that symbols in global_symbols might get overridden during the processing of the external files. That's ok.
And yes I want to merge them because I want one global code enviroment that is provided to the "other" code objects. Is there any way to do this without this potential "override" effect? Multiple dicts would not be passable to exec and multiple calls to exec would not help either. So do you see a way to keep all definitions intact when they are in fact globally used?! I don't think that's possible at all.

Comment: Well, yep, your suggestion to add local_symbol to the file_symbols dictionary as the only element does indeed work! I still do not understand why! What exactly does the statement `exec code in dict` mean more that updating the dict with all symbols found in the code?! I want to be able to understand it completely! :) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @OliK: `exec code in d` executes `code` as if it were module-level code in a module whose global variable dict is `d`. Any functions defined in `code` will remember that `d` is their global variable dict, and any global variable assignments made by `code` will remain visible in `d`.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification :) This way it makes sense what is happening now and why it works. I did not know that `dict` is used as an input, too and thought it would only be used as output. Although logically speaking it does make sense as the `in` keyword points in that direction. However I still think that the semantic meaning of the syntax in this case is pretty exotic. But now I know what it means :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The simple explanation is that you pass in `func` in the local namespace. `aFunction` does not have access to the locals you passed in (it has its own locals). All `aFunction` has access to is its own locals and its module's globals. `func` is in neither of these and so the function call fails.

Most normal modules work with their globals and locals as the same namespace (you can check this out yourself `assert globals() is locals()`). This is why you can define things at the module level and have them available to any defined functions (all names in a module are automatically global).

To make this work you need to make locals and globals the same `dict`, or just not pass locals at all. If you don't want globals to be mutated, then just copy globals and then add `func` to it.

```
src = """
def aFunction():
    a = func.func_1()
    b = func.func_2()
    return a + b
value = aFunction()
"""

class Functions:
    def func_1(self):
        return "first"
    def func_2(self):
        return "second"
functions = Functions()

compiled_code = compile(src, "<string>", "exec")

global_env = {}
local_env = {"func":functions}
namespace = dict(global_env)
namespace.update(local_env)
exec(compiled_code, namespace)
print(namespace["value"])
```

Comment: Hmm, well, okay actually my scenario is much more complex like the one I posted. Maybe thats a bit of a problem. But I wanted to keep it simple. Maybe too simple :} So what I need to actually do is not only to compile external files but to convert them to a dictionary that can be used for other compiled code. So what I really do is call `exec compiled_code in definitions` for the external file that needs to access e.g. `func`. With the accumulated dict I execute other compiled code objects. So multiple external files make up one dictionary for "final" code objects that come from elsewhere.

Comment: @Oli I'm not sure I really understand. Do you mean something vaguely like -- https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b9f131cb316e3d79c1d65cc9d46b26a7

Comment: The problem occurs when calling `exec compiled_code in definitions`. But I need to do it this way because I want to generate a "code environment" that can be used for other compiled code objects. So how would I collect compiled definitions in a dictionary when there is still  the need to access any local variables (coming from the code that actually compiles the external code) in the compiled code?
The solution that I posted as an answer to my own question works. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: No, I do not actually exec any code at this point really. In my example in the OP I did, yes. But in my actual project's code it is one step more complicated as I first call `exec compiled_code in definitions` which gives me a dictionary of all symbols in the compiled code which can then be used as a local_env for other compiled code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Please review my updated question as this is the real problem that I face.

Answer (score 0):

it is an interesting question, thanks for posting it. I've been taking a look at how to change the `globals` table in compile time. Apparently, you can call the `__import__()` function directly and:

> pass your globals in order to determine how to interpret the name in a package context.

Source: [Package documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

Comment: Thanks for answering but actually I did not find a way how to use `__import__()` so that my goal can be reached. Calling `__import__("func", global_env, local_env)` where `global_env = {"func" : functions }` will always produce and `ImportError` because the module "func" does not actually exist anywhere other than as a local variable in the module that compiles the code. The problem is that I need to bind this local variable to a global symbol so that the compiler can resolve it during compilation. How would I do this with `__import__()`?

Comment: Following further links in your link it seems that I have to install a hook for the Importer Protocol as it can be found here: [Import Hooks + The Importer Protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#specification-part-2-registering-hooks)
However I have not yet figured out how to actually use it...I am reading it right now...

Comment: Yes. I'm having a look as well.

Comment: I am rather sure that this mechanism provides the solution. I would have to add a `import func` to the loaded code and force the importer by using a hook to import my object instead of any actual file. But the how-to is still a bit of a mystery. My tests so far remain unsuccessful...

Comment: But maybe it's as simple as adding the `func` object temporarily to the `sys.modules` dict before actually compiling the code and then removing this entry again. It will try this and post the results soon.

Comment: Added my current solution as answer :)

Comment: Please review my updated question as this is the real problem that I face.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously it works by simply adding (and potentially removing - if using multiple "func" instances) the instance to sys.modules:

```
sys.modules["func"] = functions
(...)
compiled_code = compile(code, "<string>", "exec")
```

The complete and working solution including an importer hook (which intercepts "import func" lines in source code files) would look like this:

```
import sys

class Functions:
    def __init__(self):
        (...)
    def func_1(...):
        (...)
    def func_2(...):
        (...)
    (...)
    def func_n(...):
        (...)

functions = Functions()
code = loadSomeFile(...)

hook_name = "func"

class ImporterHook:
    def __init__(self, path):
        if path != hook_name:
            raise ImportError()
    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        return self
    def load_module(self, path):
        if sys.modules.has_key(path):
            return sys.modules[path]
        else:
            sys.modules[path] = functions
            return functions

sys.path_hooks.append(ImporterHook)
sys.path.insert(0, hook_name)
compiled_code = compile(code, "<string>", "exec")
(...)
exec(compiled_code)
```

Not so hard as it seems :) For more information see here:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#specification-part-2-registering-hooks

and here:

https://pymotw.com/2/sys/imports.html

THANKS :)

Comment: Well done! Thanks for this question, it has been rather interesting for me.

Comment: Ah! I suggest to "approve" your own question. Thus you'll help the community to quickly find your answer.

Comment: Have you even read what I intend to do? There is NO real file for the import available! Instead I am using an instance of a class that is only available during runtime. This is a rather complex scenario...

Comment: @OliK: I've read your question, and there's no mention of trying to `import func` or anything like that. Why are you trying to do this as an import?

Comment: Simply read everything! As I said this is a pretty complex scenario!

Comment: @user2357112: If you see any simpler solution for binding code local class instances to external code files feel free to post your solution here. I am happy to review your solution!

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying. Please review my updated question as this is the real problem that I face.

Comment: Although the import hook solution works there is a much simpler one which I have accepted as the solution to my case. As the simple solution is stated in a comment I have posted it as another update to my OP. Thanks everyone for helping :)